# Custom timeline view over two days, but only showing time between

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I'm looking to present a custom timeline view that spans over two days, but shows the first day from 10pm, until the next day at 7am. Something that fits within a night shift.

e.g. 21/06/2019 from 10pm until 22/06/2019 at 7am.

I've tried using minTime and maxTime with a custom 2 day timeline view, but with minTime being 22:00 and maxTime as 07:00, it's confusing the calendar and no days show up.

I'd rather not use businessHours, because i'm rather limited with screen space (the company that uses the app typically use laptops), so if i can limit the times completely with something similar to minTime and maxTime somehow, that would be great.

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried with the `validRange` option?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Found a solution that I've posted below. Typically not long after i ask the question

Answer (score 0):

Well, not long after i posted i found a solution.

So for anyone else that has the same issue as me, all you need to do is set your maxTime accordingly as below:

So for a 10pm start - minTime of 22:00:00.

For a 7am finish the next day - maxTime would need to be 31:00:00 (24 + 7) and not 07:00:00.

No need for a 2 day timeline view either :)

Comment: I'm fairly sure I saw a question a few months ago where someone had done exactly this, and superficially it worked but then it gave them some other problems down the line. I'll see if I can dig it up, cos I think we found a solution in the end.